# How can I change the voice used for Apple Maps?

Tags: iphone, maps

I'm using an iPhone XR running iOS 15.1. A recent upgrade changed the default voice used for giving directions in Apple Maps. How can I change the voice back to what was previously used?

Answer (score 1):

To change the default voice used for Apple Maps directions, do the following:

1. Open Settings> Siri & Search
2. If "Press Side Button for Siri" is off:

   1. Turn on "Press Side Button for Siri"
   2. Select "Voice 4"
   3. Turn off "Press Side Button for Siri"
3. If "Press Side Button for Siri" is on:

   1. Tap "Siri Voice"
   2. For the "Variety" option, select "American"
   3. For the "Voice" option, select "Voice 4"